# Disable initial animation in D3 with webcola js

Tags: animation, d3.js, force-layout, disable, webcola

I want to disable that first animation, because it leeks the browser in big graphs.
The documentation is frightful and I don't what to use d3 force layout, I want to keep webcola.

Thanks

Comment: can you add a working snippet of your D3 graph implementation, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable animation in a force-directed graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510853/how-to-disable-animation-in-a-force-directed-graph)